# fbm in R package somebm generates one value more

Tags: r

I am using a package "somebm" to generate a sample following a fractional Brownian motion process with a certain hurst index.
I noticed that, if I generate a data of length 1000, for instance, the fbm would return me a vector of length 1001.
So, for example, here

d <- fbm(hurst=0.2, n=1000)

d will have length 1001 instead of 1000. Could someone explain me why?

Thank you in advance!